# Using form input in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to allow the user to enter an `"access code"` which is simply a `timestamp`, and then start a `countdown` timer based on that. I can set the var manually and it works, but I cannot get it from the form. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="access" onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {

    function formChanged() {
        var access = document.getElementsByName("access")[0].value;
    }

    //var access = 1443564011;
    var note = $('#note'),
        // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
        ts = (new Date(access * 1000)).getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;


    $('#countdown').countdown({
        timestamp: ts,
        callback: function(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {

            var message = "";

            message += days + "<small class='white'>D</small>, " + access;
            message += hours + "<small class='white'>H</small>, ";
            message += minutes + "<small class='white'>M</small>, ";
            message += seconds + "<small class='white'>S</small>";

            note.html(message);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Error in the developer console should have pointed you to the problem.

Comment: What developer console?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/console/console-ui Every modern day browser has them. Learn to use them.

Comment: I thought you meant a specific one based on how you said it. Yes ofcourse but I still can't find the problem

Comment: 1. From the code here, it looks like the variable `ts` is set only once and it is set before the user gets s chance to enter any input. Perhaps you should move the countdown () call to inside `formChanged`   2. You're already using jQuery. Go ahead and make it easy on you self to bind `formChanged`. `$('form input[name=access]').on ('keypress change',formChanged);`

Answer (score 1):

```
function formChanged() {
    var access = document.getElementsByName("access")[0].value;
}
```

You have a problem of variable scope. When you define your variable access using the var keyword inside that function, it is only accessible inside that function. You should move the var statement out of the function and it should work.

```
var access = 0;
function formChanged() {
    access = parseInt($("input[name=access]").val(), 10);
}
```

You could also add some validation code to make sure that they input a number, as nothing in your current code handles the case where the user doesn't input a number.

Comment: I tried that and it outputed Pre-sale ends in NaND, undefinedNaNH, NaNM, NaNS

Comment: You're using jQuery, so I'm not sure why you're not using jQuery selectors in the first place. I'll update my answer.